# How to preserve single space or tab between certain characters while removing it from other characters?

Tags: c#

I need a C# solution to clean up some names, to remove any space or tab, leading or trailing and from between characters, specific letters. If the last letter and first letter of a word have the same case then remove the space. Otherwise leave a single space.

**Example:**

Before: `Rob ert   Pla nt`

After: `Robert Plant`

Or

Before: `Ro bert Plant`

After: `Robert Plant`

Note that the space is removed because o and b are the same case but t and P is reserved because P is upper case and t is lower.

The best I can do so far is this:

```
    public static string RemoveMultiSpace(string input)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+", " ");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.Write(RemoveMultiSpace("Ro bert              Plant"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

This is the output: `Ro bert Plant` but I need an output like: `Robert Plant`

Comment: This starts to get tricky with input like `Ro bert Plant`, unless you take casing into account.  It seems that you want to a) Remove spacing between lower-case letters, and b) remove all occurrences of more-than-one space in a row.

Comment: @EricJ. I am only using the name Robert Plant as an example: This will be the same for any letters of words that match regardless of the name. Example: `Cha rlie     Brown` becomes `Charlie Brown`.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy, are you saying that every first and second name starts with an uppercase letter?

Comment: The question would appear to be making that assumption, certainly.

Comment: @ClickRick, yes; I work with a colleague called Mark de Villiers!

Comment: @DanielJamesBryars: Thanks for Pointing that out, I was thinking a name like that will be: `Mark De Villiers.` Some are that way. But you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to detect spaces which have lower-case letters on both sides:

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s+(?=[a-z])|\s(?=\s)
```

It also removes duplicate spaces with the part `\s(?=\s)`.

In the code it looks like:

```
public static string RemoveMultiSpace(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s+(?=[a-z])|\s(?=\s)", "");
}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks: The above leaves a space if there are multiple spaces, instead of removing all spaces between the letters.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy Can you give an example when it doesn't work? It works for the examples you gave above.

Comment: Ok, to cater for all duplicate spaces in all positions and then removing spaces between lower-case letters, I made it a two-step process.

Comment: This is what I tried, I know the question wasn't posed this way but depending on the number of tabs, it does not work: Example: `R o be    rt Plant` becomes `Ro bert Plant`

Comment: @UnaverageGuy Sorry, didn't cater for upper case followed by lower case. Updated it now.

Comment: @ClickRick You cannot use \s+ as it won't remove duplicate space between t and P in "Rob ert    Plant". You have to remove it separately.

Comment: @ClickRick You're right (blush) Got confused by my own regex. Ok, settled on the version that I updated now. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using some `LINQ`:

```
public static string RemoveMultiSpace(string input)
{
    var indices = input
              .Select((x, idx) => new { x, idx })
              .Where(c => char.IsUpper(c.x))
              .Select(c => c.idx);

    return new string(input
            .Where((x, idx) =>  indices.Any(c => c - 1  == idx) || x != ' ')
            .ToArray());
}
```

Maybe code looks complicated but it's basically getting all the indexes of capital letters, then filter the letters, if the *white-space* comes before a capital letter it includes it, otherwise it removes the space.

[`Here`](http://dotnetfiddle.net/GUJ6LV) is the working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the spaces and then insert one on the second capital letter found.

```
        String f = "Char lie Brow n";
        f = f.Replace(" ", "");
        int breakLocation = -1;
        for (int i = 1; i < f.Length; i++)
        {
            if (f[i].ToString() == f[i].ToString().ToUpper())
            {
                breakLocation = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (breakLocation > 0)
        {
            f = f.Insert(breakLocation, " ");
        }

        MessageBox.Show(f);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the code that manually does it.

```
        public static string RemoveMultiSpace(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) { return "Wrong input"; }

        input = input.TrimEnd().TrimStart();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int x = 0; x < input.Length; x++)
        {
            // add letter if not space or tab
            if (input[x] != ' ' && input[x] != '\t')
            {
                result.Append(input[x]);
            }
            else
            {
                char char2Append = input[x];
                char lastLetter = input[x - 1];
                char firstLetter = '\0';

                //find first letter of the next word
                while (input[x + 1] == ' ' || input[x + 1] == '\t')
                {
                    x++;
                }

                firstLetter = input[x + 1];

                if (lastLetter >= 97 && lastLetter <= 122 && firstLetter >= 65 && firstLetter <= 90)
                {
                    result.Append(char2Append);
                }
            }
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```