# Preserving single space or tab between specific characters in a name while removing it from other characters?

Tags: c#

I posted a question yesterday: [See question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280796/how-to-preserve-single-space-or-tab-between-certain-characters-while-removing-it), about preserving single space or tab between certain characters while removing it from other characters.

To avoid confusion and extending the discussion, I am re-posting a modified version of the question.

I need a C# solution to clean up some names, to remove any space or tab, leading or trailing and from between *specific characters or specific letters*. If the last letter and first letter of a word have the same case then remove the space. Otherwise leave a single space.

Below are examples:

Before: `Bo  b Marley`

After: `Bob Marley`

Or

Before: `B  ob Mar  ley`

After: `Bob Marley`

The problem is, what happens if there are names like `Brian de Palma` Or `Oscar de la Hoya`?

I need a way to handle the `de` and `la` or to make exceptions.

**So far this:**

```
public static string RemoveMultiSpace(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s+(?=[a-z])|\s(?=\s)", "");
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write(RemoveMultiSpace("Brian   de    Palma"));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output: `Briande Palma` instead of `Brian de Palma`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The best I can come up with is a table of known name parts like "de" and "la". However, how would you handle "Shei la Smith"? Is that "Sheila Smith" or "Shei la Smith"?

Comment: angela ? This will be nigh on impossible to get 100% accurate.

Comment: The first thing you need is a list of small caps name parts. This list may well grow in time, so don't hard code it into your clean-up algorithm. Here are a few more: de di van von zu der... You could replace each of these, ie " de " etc by something like "_de_" etc, then clean-up those spaces and finally restore the small name parts.

Comment: How much time are you going to invest in maintaining the exceptions list (which has no known upper bound on its size)? [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: I already have a name database that I have been building. This is simply another avenue, I have about 200,000 names to match and growing. Again, I am simply looking at other areas. No solution is 100 percent possible. Even the U.S NASA Space program is not 100% safe. I am not looking for that, just possibilities.

Comment: How would someone search for "Bo B. Marley" if they were so inclined?